# Django changed files not synchronizing changes on ubuntu nginx gunicorn

Tags: django, ubuntu, nginx, gunicorn

My django project working fine which is deployed on **ubuntu server with nginx, Gunicorn**. But when I make changes in **Template files, Views, Forms, Models** and upload using Filezilla, No changes synchronize/ Or *project is not showing made changes by me*.
Can scholars and seniors help in this please.

Comment: You need to use supervisor or systemd to restart your application process for the changes to show.

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help if you are using gunicorn sock file

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart gunicorn
sudo nginx -t && sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

you can read from [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04#install-the-packages-from-the-ubuntu-repositories)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have run $sudo systemctl daemon-reload
$sudo nginx -t && sudo systemctl restart nginx these file but ***$sudo systemctl restart gunicorn this command gives error message*** "Failed to restart gunicorn.service: Unit gunicorn.service not found.
"